# ¿Cómo usa Sort los resultados de Compare para ordenar un Array?

Tags: java, array, comparaciones, ordenamiento

Encontré la siguiente forma de ordenar un array de Strings, por la longitud de cada string. Me funciona.
Pero no entiendo bien **como** lo hace.

Entiendo que **sort** es un método de Arrays, que recibe un Array y un Comparator.
¿Por qué se hace la resta entre el la longitud de los elementos?

En la documentación de **compare** dice:
*Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.*

¿Cómo los usa sort para ordenar la lista?

```
    String[] strArr = { "ABCD", "AB", "ABCDEFG", "ABC", "A", "ABCDE", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEFGHIJ" };
    Arrays.sort(strArr, (str1, str2) -> str1.length() - str2.length());
    System.out.println("toString: " + Arrays.toString(strArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Bien el método sort tiene varias sobrecargas pero me ocuparé solo de la que preguntas. En este caso al método sort se le pasan dos parámetros, el primero que es la colección a ordenar que en este caso es el arreglo strArr y el segundo parámetro es la función comparadora expresada aquí como un método anónimo el cual recibe dos parámetros de tipo string y como tú dices devuelve un entero. Ahora bien que papel juega la resta pues sencillo

Acuérdate que estás comparando por el tamaño de la cadena

Si la primera cadena es mayor que la segunda esta resta devuelve un número positivo queriendo decir efectivamente que la primera cadena es mayor que la segunda por lo tanto se retorna un número positivo

Si la resta es 0 las dos cadenas son iguales

Si la resta es negativa quiere decir que la segunda cadena es mayor que la primera por lo que se retorna un número negativo, para eso se usa la resta espero hayas entendido